# Prove that the circle S1 is homeomorphic to a quotient of S1 such that each partition element has either one point or infinitely many points.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that the circle $S^1$ is homeomorphic to a quotient of $S^1$ such that each partition element has either one point or infinitely many points.

To clarify, I'm not understanding *how a homeomorphism would result in each partition element having the above form*. I already know that the circle is homeomorphic to its quotient group in the antipodal sense.

I'm thinking about the math using these definitions:

1. A homeomorphism is the mapping that preserves all the topological properties of a given space. A mapping $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is said to be homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective, continuous and $f^−1$ is continuous.
2. A partition of a set is a grouping of its elements into non-empty subsets, in such a way that every element is included in exactly one subset.

I've been reading through the site trying to understand homeomorphisms in general, and there seems to be more intuition needed for finding the mappings and corresponding functions for homeomorphisms than I was expecting. It could just be 2D homeomorphisms are still new to me.

Does anyone have thoughts for this particular example?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a quotient of $S^1$ that is homoemorphic to $S^1$ and each partition/fiber is singleton or infinite? Example: collapse the upper half to a point. Or are you asking if every such quotient is homeomorphic to $S^1$? Counterexample: Hawaiian earring.